# How to add taxonomy to a post using WP REST API?

Tags: rest-api

I'm using [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/), but I have a taxonomy called Ingredients to my Product custom post type.
I can create a Product posting to the endpoing `/wp-json/wp/v2/produtos`, but how can I attach a custom taxonomy (Ingredient) to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the taxonomy name to target it:

```
...,
ingredient: [121],
....
```

Where 121 will be the term_id...

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to implement this solution? Where does this code go, what does it look like in a larger piece of functional code?